# What are the best security guidelines in this AJAX scenario, with special regards to authentication?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, security

[I hope that this question is not too broad, I think that the subject is *very* interesting but I incourage you to tell me if it's off-policy.]

My scenario is this:

- I have a LAMP website who stores also sensitive data and documents
- Only registered users are allowed to operate on the site, and only on certain data and documents. Users are stored in $_SESSION variables
- Most of the pages implement a sort of rudimental permission control, but some important DB operations are called via AJAX
- AJAX security is implemented very poorly, as anyone that is that smart can tamper with the request sending whatever id they like and delete records with brutal simplicity

Asking for a complete book on security is obviously a bit too much (and I'm already reading and trying a lot on the subject), let's say that my main concern is if AJAX pages should be treated with special regards, as I need to secure the whole software to prevent hacks and other problems.

Comment: You know that the browser sends cookies with XHR requests, too? I don't see where the problem is with implementing the same kind of authorization scheme that is used by the website itself.

Comment: Was just wondering if the use of AJAX would open new scenarios to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a LAMP website who stores also sensitive data and documents

You should store as little sensitive data as possible. Especially when you are not sure how to keep this information secure/private. Use OpenID or something for your authentication for example. I really like [LightOpenID](http://gitorious.org/lightopenid) for it's simplicity. I created a little [example project/library](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid) to see lightopenId in use. It simplifies using OpenID by using [openID-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/). When you use OpenID you also use secure OpenID providers the passwords are also not transmitted over the wire in plain-text but protected by https/SSL.

> Only registered users are allowed to operate on the site, and only on
>   certain data and documents. Users are stored in $_SESSION variables

Yup that's what sessions are for.

> Most of the pages implement a sort of rudimental permission control,
>   but some important DB operations are called via AJAX

You should read up on [OWASP top 10.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010) at least. (**Don’t stop at 10.**)

> AJAX security is implemented very poorly, as anyone that is that smart
>   can tamper with the request sending whatever id they like and delete
>   records with brutal simplicity

See previous section. Read up on OWASP top 10 section at least. Somethings which a lot of people overlook for example are [CSRF](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries) for example.

Comment: Unluckily I *have* to store this data: it's a regional-governative  site that companies in a certain field are *required* to use for certain activities (sending/requesting documents and so on in particular scenarios), the companies are a lot (17K) and it's mantained by only two programmers.
That's why hardening the code is so crucial (yes, I acknowledge that the developing scenario is far from ideal, very expert programmers aware of most security issues were the ideal choice, but that's how things are and little can be done to change the status quo for many reasons...).

Comment: if possible firewall the shit out of your site. Only allow users who should have access to those parts. Use SSL. Monitoring is also very important. The earlier you can spot intrusion(hopefully not) the better you can defend yourself....

Comment: SSL is already used. We have logs and all, fail2ban for ssh attacks.

Comment: Not just for ssh attacks, I would use it to protect my webserver from attacks from IP's which should not be able to attack your webserver.

Answer (score 3):

> let's say that my main concern is if AJAX pages should be treated with special regards

Not really. They should be treated almost exactly the same as any other request. **All** HTTP requests come from outside your system and are under the control of the client (so can consist of, more or less, anything the user can imagine).

You might be returning JSON, you might be returning a complete HTML document, you might be returning XML — but the format doesn't matter, the data does.

If the request is for sensitive data, then you need (on the server) to authenticate the user and then make sure they are authorised to view / edit that data.

The only difference is how you present a "You are not authorised" message. You can't simply return an HTML document with a login form when you expect the browser to load data into XHR. The response needs to be appropriately formatted and the JavaScript needs to be able to handle it.

Comment: +1 This may come as a shock to the OP, but even regular "non-AJAX" requests can be perfectly tempered with.

Comment: Absolutely not. And for those I've already taken measures (addressing SQL injection, data filtering, permissions). My concern was if AJAX would open new scenarios to deal with.

Comment: @Cranio: Rather than trying to prevent certain kinds of "scenarios", you should use common sense and just always sanitize user input appropriately. The same applies to non-HTML requests.

Comment: That's what I am *already* doing, as commented. Input sanitization is not enough nor the only security measure, right?